# What happens if an Impala query runs out of memory?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala

What happens if an Impala query runs out of memory:

1. Does the Impala daemon crash?
2. Does it write to the disk?

A detailed explanation would help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the version of Impala and how it's configured.

In general, Impala will kill queries when they run out of memory. There is a process-wide memory limit at which point any query that requests memory will be killed. There is also another optional, per-query memory limit.

Impala 2.0 and later support "spilling" large join and aggregation operators which help avoid these out of memory conditions.

Comment: We are thinking of building a Queuing system over Impala which will limit the number of simultaneous queries submitted to the cluster (join or aggregation) to avoid spillage. Is this a good idea?

Comment: Impala has a built in mechanism for this. See: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/v5-2-x/topics/impala_admission.html

Comment: What effect can impala jobs have on other jobs like maybe a map-reduce job or hive job in case its nearing peak memory on the same cluster?